# Unit Testing transitions in D3 version 4

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, d3.js, svg, transition

In older versions of D3 you where able to make unit tests that checked the state of a D3 component after all of the transitions had completed by flushing the timer like this d3.timer.flush(). In D3 version 4 you need to d3.timerFlush(), however this is not completing all of the the transitions for me. Only the first transition is completed.

Reading https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/BioLtR9ixYE I can see that one solution is to use an async testing framework like tape, but unfortunately I cannot change my test runner at this time.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 doesn't have a built in way to flush through transition delays or durations. You can variablize the values though and set them to 0 for your test.

If the delay or duration is 0 you will still have to do a d3.timerFlush() in your test, but it will complete the entire transition now.